# QML ListModel append broken for object containing an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, qt, qml, listmodel

`ListModel` produces unexpected and pretty much broken results when trying to insert a JS object which contains an array:

```
property ListModel model : ListModel {}

Component.onCompleted: {
  var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  console.log(a)
  model.append({"a" : a})
  console.log(model.get(model.count - 1))
  console.log(model.get(model.count - 1).a)
```

Output is:

```
qml: [1,2,3,4,5]
qml: QObject(0x3cccd58)
qml: QQmlListModel(0x3cd0978)
```

However, if the array is joined into a string, it works as expected:

```
  console.log(a)
  a = a.join(",")
  model.append({"a" : a})
  console.log(model.get(model.count - 1))
  console.log(model.get(model.count - 1).a)

qml: [1,2,3,4,5]
qml: QObject(0x3d5da60)
qml: 1,2,3,4,5
```

A few observations - it seems like the array is somehow "converted" to a `QQmlListModel`, and it is another list model instance, not the one that's being appended to. Also, initially I though this might indeed be some auto conversion and expected that list model to contain the five numbers and indeed `count` is 5, however `get(0)` returns an `undefined`. So while the size matches that of the array, there isn't any valid content whatsoever.

I am pretty sure it is a bug, but nevertheless I'd ask if someone knows what is going on before filing a bug report.

Comment: The `array` is indeed converted into a `ListModel`, but you have no roles defined. Try to append `[ { val: 1 }, { val: 2 }, { val: 3 } ]` - Now you will have something to `get(0)` to.

Comment: Except that in that case the intent is just to have an array as data, not a model.

Answer (score 0):

From [the `ListModel` docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#details):

> The ListModel is a simple container of ListElement definitions [...]

If you then go to the [documentation of `ListElement`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html#details):

> **Values must be simple constants**; either strings (quoted and optionally within a call to QT_TR_NOOP), boolean values (true, false), numbers, or enumeration values (such as AlignText.AlignHCenter).

Comment: I don't see how a string is a "simpler constant" than an array. A string is an array plus extra stuff. Also, it does work OK with Qt objects references...

Comment: @dtech Remember, the code here is JS; a JS string is not a JS array.

Comment: You might want to revise that answer in light of https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59704 , evidently arrays should be supported, and there is a bug associated with it.